# Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/tmp/sess_qj0mc0b3pr039hn4a6kgs0rld2, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, session, file-permissions

I'm working on Symfony 2.8
I change the permission of many files and folders
But ... the problem stay there ... 
When i create the project, i fail in the values but i edited them in the parameters.yml so it's not that.

This is the screenshoot about the error.

I think it's about mysql or something like that ... what do you think?

I'm noob and the english is not my native language, so, sry for the mistakes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1mCS.jpg)

Comment: If simply means that the user apache is not allowed to access that file. Change the owner, group or permissions on the server to let apache access it

Comment: Thanks FMashiro for your advice, but i delete the project and create it again and now is fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have  fix this issue in MacOS FastCGI Process Manager (FPM) & Nginx

```
cd cd /var/tmp/


sudo rm -rf sess_*
```

Then warning is not coming.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the entire project and create it again with the corresponding values on the user_database and password :)
sry for the discomfort